# Create string from array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, unnest

I have a table in PostgreSQL that contains:

```
id   name   arrayofparents
1     First
2     Second      {1}
3     Second_Sec  {1,2}
4     Third       {1,2,3}
5     Second_A    {1}
6     Other
7     Trash       {6}
```

`arrayofparents` is of type `integer[]` it contains a list of the parents records for that row with the correct order.

`id=4` parents are: `First` then `Second` then  `Second_sec`

How do I write a query that for any given id it will generate a string of it's parents name?

for example:

`id=3`: `First->Second`.

`id=4`: `First->Second->Second_sec`.

`id=7`: `Other`.

**Edit:**
if possible I prefer the requested id `name` will always appear.
`id=3`: `First->Second->Second_sec`.

`id=4`: `First->Second->Second_sec->Third`.

`id=7`: `Other->Trash`.

`id=6`: `Other`.

Comment: This is a bad DB design as (to my knowledge) you cannot enforce referential integrity with an array type (see http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60132/foreign-key-constraint-on-array-member ). I recommend changing your design to use a "join table", then you can use a recursive CTE to solve your problem.

Comment: The field arrayofparents is used for other porpuses.. mostly to with Any query.... I just wanted to take advantage of it. I can not change the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can combine muliple operations like generate_subscripts and array to get the result:

```
with mtab as (
      SELECT id, name, array_append(arrayofparents,id) as arrayofparents,
      generate_subscripts(array_append(arrayofparents, id), 1) AS p_id FROM tab where id=2
)
select distinct array_to_string(
  array(
    select tab.name from tab join mtab t on tab.id=t.arrayofparents[t.p_id]
  ), '->'
) ;
```

[**live example Sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3a0fd8/78/0)

or use outer join combined with any:

```
SELECT coalesce(string_agg(p.name, '->') || '->' || t.name, t.name) AS parentnames
FROM tab AS t
  LEFT JOIN tab AS p ON p.id = ANY(t.arrayofparents)
 where t.id =7 
GROUP BY t.id, t.name
```

[**live example Sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3a0fd8/63/0)

Comment: it doesn't work... check it on `id=7` it gives `First`.... it should give `Other`

Comment: Question.. if I also want to add the current id name ? for example `id=7`  :  `Other -> Trash`. instad of  `Other`. meaning add the current id name at the end every time.  is it doable?

Comment: it's working but it doesn't make sure that Trash is at the end. the union cause the order to be massed up. it can generate Trash-> Other.

Comment: can you try the second option?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97113/discussion-between-mohamed-el-housseine-and-avi).

Comment: your second example does the order correctly but  it doesn't work on the the "head" id's... in ur sql fiddle id=6. it returns no rows. it should include at least the id name

Comment: i modified the second version (the new first version) and it can now return all items

Comment: Both queries are not guaranteed to retain the original order of elements in  their current state.

Answer (score 1):

Each of these queries work for a single id as well as for the whole table.
And you can return just the path / the full path or all other columns as well.

```
SELECT t.*, concat_ws('->', t1.path, t.name) AS full_path
FROM   tbl t
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT string_agg(t1.name, '->' ORDER  BY i) AS path
   FROM   generate_subscripts(t.arrayofparents, 1) i
   JOIN   tbl t1 ON t1.id = t.arrayofparents[i]   
   ) t1 ON true
WHERE  t.id = 4;  -- optional
```

Alternatively, you could move the `ORDER BY` to a subquery - may be a bit faster:

```
SELECT concat_ws('->', t1.path, t.name) AS full_path
FROM   tbl t, LATERAL (
   SELECT string_agg(t1.name, '->') AS path
   FROM  (
      SELECT t1.name
      FROM   generate_subscripts(t.arrayofparents, 1) i
      JOIN   tbl t1 ON t1.id = t.arrayofparents[i]
      ORDER  BY i
      ) t1
   ) t1
WHERE  t.id = 4;  -- optional
```

Since the aggregation happens in the `LATERAL` subquery we don't need a `GROUP BY` step in the outer query.

We also don't need `LEFT JOIN LATERAL ... ON true` to retain all rows where `arrayofparents` is NULL or empty, because the `LATERAL` subquery *always* returns a row due to the aggregate function.
`LATERAL` requires Postgres **9.3**.

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

Use [`concat_ws()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) to ignore possible NULL values in the concatenation.

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/387f2/1)

`WITH OTDINALITY` makes it a bit simpler and faster in Postgres **9.4**:

```
SELECT t.*, concat_ws('->', t1.path, t.name) AS full_path
FROM   tbl t, LATERAL (
   SELECT string_agg(t1.name, '->' ORDER BY ord) AS path
   FROM   unnest(t.arrayofparents) WITH ORDINALITY a(id,ord)
   JOIN   tbl t1 USING (id)  
   ) t1
WHERE  t.id = 4;
```

Detailed explanation:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

---

Variant with `UNION ALL` for pg 9.3

```
SELECT t1.full_path
FROM   tbl t, LATERAL (
   SELECT string_agg(name, '->') AS full_path
   FROM  (
      (
      SELECT name
      FROM   generate_subscripts(t.arrayofparents, 1) i
      JOIN   tbl ON id = t.arrayofparents[i]
      ORDER  BY i
      )
      UNION ALL SELECT t.name
      ) t1
   ) t1
WHERE  t.id = 4;
```

Comment: Can you show how to make sure that the id will always appear? see my question edit.

Comment: unnest doesn't keep the order... it messes up the records.. it can show  Second->First->Second_sec instad of First->Second->Second_sec

Comment: @avi: Right, well mostly. Just like I explained in detail in the linked answer. `unnest()` itself reains the original order, but the *join* messes with it. I fixed that. Plus, the join condition was also missing. And I added the name of the current row according to your Q update. Each of these queries should now be faster than the currently accepted answer (besides being correct). Test with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want direct parents (not grandparents) then something like this should work:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, string_agg(p.name, '->') AS parentnames
FROM yourtable AS c
  LEFT JOIN yourtable AS p ON p.id = ANY c.parents
GROUP BY c.id, c.name
```

Comment: it says: ERROR: syntax error at or near "c". I need all parents from what is written in arrayofparents