# Importing character varying column to character varying array column in PSQL

Tags: arrays, postgresql

Using PostgreSQL 9.4.

I have a data column titled 'Appliances'. 'Appliances' is of type character varying and is full of values that follow this patter: 'A|B|E|H' or 'C|D|E', etc. I also have a text file that explains the mappings that define what the capital letters mean, i.e. A=Dishwasher, B=Stove, C=Microwave...

I need to convert this data to a fit into a new character varying array column, such that the values become: '{Dishwasher, Stove, Fan, Television}'

The first thing I tried was stacking a whole bunch of replace calls on top of each other and concatenating with '{' and '}':

```
select 
'{' || 
replace(replace(replace(
replace(replace(replace(
replace(replace(replace(
  replace('A|B|C|D|E|F|G|J|I', '|', ','),
    'G', 'Refrigerator'),
    'D', 'Garbage Disposal'),
    'A', 'Dishwasher') ,
    'B', 'Double Oven'),
    'C', 'Dryer'),
    'E', 'Microwave'),
    'F', 'Range/Oven'),
    'I', 'Trash Compactor'),
    'J', 'Washer')
|| '}'
```

not only does this look gross, but it breaks when you switch the Refrigerator and the Garbage Disposal. Because of the 'G' in 'Garbage Disposal'. Another problem is I could conceivably add an appliance later that would make a circular replacement that would prevent this method form working at all.

SO, is there a better way to handle this situation?

Comment: You should give hstore a try :) http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html

Comment: *Always* declare your version of Postgres please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [@Bill already hinted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34194212/939860), the proper way to do this would be normalized schema for the many-to-many relationship between appliances and houses (or whatever is holding your collection of appliances). You would implement it with three table like:

```
house  
appliance
house_appliance
```

Details:

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)

---

While **stuck with your current schema**, there are multiple solutions possible - depending on your version of Postgres and the ***precise*** definition of what you have and what you need.

Building on this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE appliance (
  appliance_id "char" PRIMARY KEY
, appliance     text NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO appliance VALUES
  ('G', 'Refrigerator')
, ('D', 'Garbage Disposal')
, ('A', 'Dishwasher') 
, ('B', 'Double Oven')
, ('C', 'Dryer')
, ('E', 'Microwave')
, ('F', 'Range/Oven')
, ('I', 'Trash Compactor')
, ('J', 'Washer')
;

CREATE TABLE house (
  house_id   serial PRIMARY KEY
, appliances text
);

INSERT INTO house(appliances) VALUES
  ('A|B|C|D|E|F|G|J|I')
, ('G|A|F')
, ('B|Z|A')  -- special case: invalid reference
, ('B|F|')   -- special case: empty after separator
, ('')       -- special case: empty string
, (NULL)     -- special case: NULL
;
```

#### Some possible solutions

(Out of many.)

To return an actual **array** - so the text representation is wrapped in `'{}'` automatically, and any special characters are escaped.

For Postgres **9.4+**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   house h
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY (
      SELECT a.appliance
      FROM   unnest(string_to_array(h.appliances, '|'))
                  WITH ORDINALITY ha(appliance_id, ord)
      LEFT   JOIN appliance a USING (appliance_id)
      ORDER  BY ha.ord
      ) AS appl_arr
   ) a ON TRUE;
```

`WITH ORDINALITY` was introduced with Postgres 9.4. Details:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

For Postgres **9.3**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT house_id, string_to_array(appliances, '|') AS arr FROM house) h
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY (
      SELECT a.appliance
      FROM   generate_subscripts(h.arr, 1) i
      LEFT   JOIN appliance a ON a.appliance_id = arr[i]
      ORDER  BY i
      ) AS appl_arr
   ) a ON TRUE;
```

`LATERAL` requires Postgres 9.3.
Both of these versions include a NULL value in the result for invalid or missing keys. Replace the inner `LEFT JOIN` with `JOIN` to ignore invalid or missing keys. The result still includes *all* rows due to the outer `LEFT JOIN`.

For Postgres **9.2 or older**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   house h
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT '{' || string_agg(appliance, ', ') || '}' AS appl_string
   FROM  (
      SELECT a.appliance
      FROM   generate_series(1, (length (h.appliances) + 1)/ 2) i
      LEFT   JOIN appliance a ON a.appliance_id = split_part(h.appliances, '|', i)
      ORDER  BY i
      ) sub
   ) a ON TRUE;
```

Assuming that keys are a single characters exclusively.
This returns a plain string, no escaping. You can have it either way ...

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0d379/2)

Closely related:

- [Create string from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115202/create-string-from-array/34117782#34117782)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this.

```
create table appliances (
  code text primary key,
  dscr text not null);

insert into appliances (code, dscr)
values ('G', 'Refrigerator'),
    ('D', 'Garbage Disposal'),
    ('A', 'Dishwasher') ,
    ('B', 'Double Oven'),
    ('C', 'Dryer'),
    ('E', 'Microwave'),
    ('F', 'Range/Oven'),
    ('I', 'Trash Compactor'),
    ('J', 'Washer');

select array_agg(appliances.dscr)
from regexp_split_to_table('A|E|G', '\|')
join appliances on code=regexp_split_to_table;
```

Results in:

```
{Dishwasher,Microwave,Refrigerator}
```

You could left join if you want unknown codes to show as NULL, e.g.

```
select array_agg(appliances.dscr)
from regexp_split_to_table('A|E|G|?', '\|')
left join appliances on code=regexp_split_to_table;
```

Results in:

```
{Dishwasher,Microwave,Refrigerator,NULL}
```

Honestly though, you're probably better off in the long run if you split the 'A|E|G' strings into their individual codes and have a row for each entry.