# postgresql array_length to int variable

Tags: arrays, postgresql, function, variables, plpgsql

I have an array of strings

```
sarr := array['s', 's1', ..., 'sn'];
a integer;
```

I need to put array_length(sarr, 1) to a integer variable:

`a := select(array_length(sarr, 1))` or `a := array_length(sarr, 1)` doesn't work

**a** variable used here only

```
for iter in 1..a
loop
    execute 'alter table temp_table add column col_' || iter || ' 
varchar;';
end loop;
```

Comment: the second one must work, what error are you getting?

Comment: `a := array_length(sarr, 1)`  should work just fine. What is the error you get?

Comment: if I declare a := 10 for example I haven't got any error and my function work normal, bur if I set a := array_length(sarr, 1) I got this: " extra data after last expected column ..."

Comment: Show us the **complete** code. "*extra data after last expected column*" is an error from the `copy` command, not a PL/pgSQL compiler error

Comment: I edited question  & add code

Answer (score 1):

There is some kind of misunderstanding. This just works in modern Postgres:

```
-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pg_temp.temp_table;
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_table (id int PRIMARY KEY);

DO
$do$
DECLARE
   sarr text[]  := array['s', 's1', 'sn'];
   a    integer;
   iter integer;
BEGIN
   a := array_length(sarr, 1);

   FOR iter IN 1..a
   LOOP
      RAISE NOTICE '%', -- safety; replace with execute after testing
   -- EXECUTE 
         'ALTER TABLE temp_table ADD COLUMN col_' || iter || ' varchar;';
   END LOOP;
END
$do$
```

But it's inefficient. Execute a single `ALTER` command adding multiple columns instead. No loop:

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   sarr text[] := array['s', 's1', 'sn'];
BEGIN
   EXECUTE (
      SELECT 'ALTER TABLE temp_table2 ADD COLUMN col_'
          || string_agg(i::text || ' varchar', ', ADD COLUMN col_')
      FROM   generate_subscripts(sarr, 1) i
      );
END
$do$;
```

Related:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)
- [Create string from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115202/create-string-from-array/34117782#34117782)